# Logic behind Iterating over a tuple in a tuple in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I can see that **s1, s2, s3** all lead to the same result.
( gives 2'nd element of each tuple)

### Why is this so?

```
train = ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e') )
s1 = tuple([x for s, x in train])
s2 = tuple([x for ss, x in train])
s3 = tuple([x for sss, x in train])
```

Comment: `s`, `ss`, `sss` are just names that hold the first value in the tuple. The length of those names have absolutely nothing to do with what type of data will be in it.

Comment: Why would it be different?

Comment: Why do you expect different results? It is basically the same code with only one variable name changing.

Comment: @idjaw thanks man that was as clear as i expected :)

Comment: Note, `s` is still available outside the list comp in Python 2; you should ideally use `_` for 'throw-away variables'

Comment: @Chris_Rands Only in Python 2. Not in Python 3. Using the `_` is fine, but in Python 3, the scoping of the names inside a comprehension are no longer available outside that scope.

Comment: @idjaw yes, agreed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this form :

```
train = ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e') )
s1 = tuple([x for s, x in train])
s2 = tuple([x for s, x in train])
s3 = tuple([x for s, x in train])
```

then `s1 == s2 == s3`. Because `s, ss, sss` are just names that hold the first value of tuple.

Answer (score 0):

`s`, `ss` and `sss` are just variable names. The rest of the code is same and because logic is what gives you different results not changing the name of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

They're all just different names for the same thing. You could replace `s` with `a` and `x` with `b`, or any other variable names you choose, and the result would still be the same. The first variable (whatever name you give it) would get the first element of the tuple, while the second variable would get the second value. Afterwards, you only take the `x`'s, meaning the second part of each tuple into your new list.

Answer (score 0):

s, ss, sss are the temporary variables that you create within the list comprehension. They basically work in the same way and contain same value